# Why when i set cookies in PHP with json array, does is show % sign?

Tags: javascript, php

When setting a cookie with array of data in javascript, I get this output:

```
{"s1q1":"test","s1q2":"test2"}
```

but when setting a cookie in php i get this output:

```
%7B%22s1q1%22%3A%22test%22%2C%22s1q2%22%3A%22test2%22%7D
```

code used in php:

```
$cookieData=array(
   's1q1' => 'test',
   's1q2' => 'test2',
);
setCookie('calcCookie', json_encode($cookieData), time()+24*60*60*1000);
```

how do I make this cookie appear like the javascript one?

Comment: just thought, is this an encoding issue?

Comment: These are URL encoding. Like ``{`` is represented by **%7B** and so on. You can read here more https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: thanks, makes sense, i just need it in the format js saves it. guess find and replace characters isn't the way to go? guess i could try decoding it on the js side using encodeURIComponent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bit clunky but this solved the issue:

```
in js:
var cookie = getCookie('calcCookie');

cookie = cookie.replace(/%7B/g, "{").replace(/%22/g, '"').replace(/%7D/g, "}").replace(/%3A/g, ":").replace(/%2C/g, ",")

cookie = JSON.parse(cookie)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are automatically URL encoded when sent, to set a raw cookie you should use the `setrawcookie` function

```
$cookieData=array(
   's1q1' => 'test',
   's1q2' => 'test2',
);
setrawcookie('calcCookie', json_encode($cookieData), time()+24*60*60*1000);
```

> **Note**: Not sure they would be appropriately decoded back when you access them.

Comment: thanks, not sure that will work though:
Cookie values cannot contain any of the following ',; \t\r\n\013\014'.

Comment: Why you don't want them to encode tho? I mean if you access them back in PHP, they should produce the same json string

Comment: yeah think thats the issue, i'm setting a cookie in php, then need to access it later in js.

Comment: If that's the case then use decodeURI function in JS

Comment: thanks Ashu, close, but still didnt decode as i needed in js:
{"s1q1"%3A"test"%2C"s1q2"%3A"test2"}. solved it by replacing characters manually.